# Is it possible to authenticate with HtmlUnit by supplying credentials without dealing with the form?

Tags: java, authentication, htmlunit

HtmlUnit communication with the remote server is based on underlying HttpClient, and the latter allows to access web sites which require authentication by providing credentials programmatically. Is it possible to do the same thing with HtmlUnit without going through the login form and its elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
webRequest.setAdditionalHeader() or webClient.addRequestHeader()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to do a request without simulate form click? You can do login with a POST method using [WebRequest API](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebRequest.html)

```
private HtmlPage login(String name, String pass) {
        WebRequest requestSettings = new WebRequest(new URL(myUrlLoginString), HttpMethod.POST);
        // Set the request parameters               
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> requestParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        requestParameters.add(new NameValuePair("login", name));
        requestParameters.add(new NameValuePair("password", pass));
        requestParameters.add(new NameValuePair("x", "66"));
        requestParameters.add(new NameValuePair("y", "28"));
        requestSettings.setRequestParameters(requestParameters);
        Page page = webClient.getPage(requestSettings);
        return (HtmlPage) page;
}
```